# Google Maps problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Well, I can't seem to "join the forum to post" on Google Maps itself, so I guess I'll ask here.
I recently noticed the following error that started happening on Google Maps Javascript API 3:

```
SCRIPT5007: 'undefined' is null or not an object  main.js, line 17 character 197
```

This `main.js` file is the one used by Google Maps, not one on my own site.
The error seems to be caused by an undefined function being called, with the error happening here:

```
f.d[ac](f.b,c)
```

`d[ac]` is a function called `apply`, but `f.d[ac]` doesn't exist.
Anyone know how I can get it to work again? Or how to actually tell Google about the problem so they can do something about it?

Thanks.

Comment: I sometimes get errors in main.js when my code has errors. can you post some code that gets that error?

Comment: Thing is, there are no errors on any other page of the site (which all use the same JS files). Furthermore, everything is in closures, so there can't be any issues with conflicting variable names... - I'll take a closer look tomorrow, when I'm more awake...

Comment: I've seen issues with certain old or misconfigured proxies mangling large JS files. Are you behind a transparent proxy? Does it always happen with the same code from different locations? What browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm behind a proxy, but I've had a large number of users confirming the problem with a variety of browsers and things. So I'm fairly sure it's a problem in the code. It could be a conflict somewhere. Like I said, I'll take a closer look tomorrow and see.

Comment: Personally, I suggest you to use OpenLayers. Since it support third party API such as Google, Bings, and Yahoo. And also less-known OpenStreetMap. And I am kinda agree with ***Adilson de Almeida Jr*** statement. We would like to see you codes. JavaScript to be precise. Maybe I can help with that. Looking forward for your editing curiosly.

Comment: This is most likely to be an error in the code calling the Maps API. I've seen this where an undefined value is passed into a Maps API function which requires a valid value.

This may only be appearing on one page because that page triggers a different set of conditions or uses different data.

f.d[ac] might exist, but be hidden in an anonymous closure or dynamically populated. It would be hard to tell without reading all of main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you recently change from Google Maps JavaScript API v2 to v3? I had that error couple of times when using the v2 implementation of certain functions. But once again finding the source of your problem will be hard not having any code to take a look at.

Comment: No, I had not changed anything when it stopped working. Similarly, I didn't change anything and this 10-month-old problem fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a function to your own code called 'f'?  That would cause this line to error.

```
function f(){
   bla;
}
```

Comment: No, unlike some people I actually give my functions meaningful names so I can remember what does what.